# How to connect to remote hosted sql server

Tags: asp.net, sql-server, hosting

I think I am doing everything right but I am not being able to access the sql server online. I have put my settings beneath. Of course the password is hidden. Any help?

[image]
[image]

Comment: Maybe leading spaces on the server name?  Or missing .wc1?  What's the error message?

Comment: Do you host it with your own server or with hosting provider?

Comment: @Douglas Thomas - with a hosting provider

Comment: I would recommend you to contact your hosting provider. I believe they have their own rules, for example port. :)

Answer (score 1):

Looks like the `Server name` should be `MSSQL1228.wc1\inst2`. You currently have `MSSQL1228\inst2`.

Answer (score 1):

Your instance name is wrong

replace `mssql1228\inst` by `mssql228.wc1\inst`

If that doesn't work try the IP address `50.57.219.8,4120`

And if that doesn't work, you might need to validate that your user has permissions to access that specific database.

Without knowing your specific error message is hard to know 100% what's wrong

Comment: I get the following error: ".Net SqlClient Data Provider Login failed for user '346191_imran'". Also I cannot replace mssql1228\inst2 as its a drop down box I have to choose from with the couple of options and this one matches the most. How do I try with the ip address?